# Stylizing specific days from the material datepicker in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

Im looking to style specific days in the datepicker object but I cant seem to get access to the DOM elements from the calendar. I tried using a view child, but that only gave me access to the picker element, not the calendar that gets created when click on the picker.

I have also tried adding a panel class to the date picker and trying to select on that, but it also doesnt seem to work. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjt5wz-ehdbdt?file=app/datepicker-start-view-example.ts

Ideally, I want to apply a class to every day that meets a specific criteria. For example, style all days prior to the selected day as yellow. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because when the `opened` event fires, the view does not contain the DOM  elements for the calendar yet.

You can wrap your code in a `setTimeout` as a workaround

```
streamOpened(event) {
   setTimeout(()=>{
   let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.endDate');
   //here elements will not be empty
   });
```

[Modified stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjt5wz-g2wizg?file=app/datepicker-start-view-example.css)

**Edit**

Following your comment, the material datepicker API has no event for listening to changes to displayed date range. As a hack, you could try manually listening to next/previous button click like this

```
constructor(private   renderer:Renderer2){}
//...
let nextBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.mat-calendar-next-button')[0];
this.renderer.listen(nextBtn, 'click', ()=>
{
  console.log('click on next')
  //Re-run logic here (probably in timeout again...)
})
```

**Edit 2**

Following your 2nd comment, here is an example that binds refresh to all calendar button clicks. That should be enough to get you going. You'll probably need to add more listener to other calendar events though

[updated demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjt5wz-rq5a6k?file=app/datepicker-start-view-example.ts)

Basically, you can try listening to all click events

```
let x =  elements[0].querySelectorAll('.mat-calendar-body-cell');
    x.forEach(y => {

      let c = new Date(y.getAttribute("aria-label"));
      if(c < this.startDate)
      {
        y.classList.add('newClass');
      } 
    });
```

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a way to rerun the code when they change the month? Right now it only works on the initial month that gets rendered https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjt5wz-nl5tx5?file=app/datepicker-start-view-example.ts

Comment: [That](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjt5wz-aykxqm?file=app/datepicker-start-view-example.ts) didnt work for me

Comment: Well that's a bit normal... In your example, you only refresh the calendar styles when clicking on **next** to change the month. But your code changes the styles for dates **BEFORE** today's date... so of course that will never be true if you click on next... you need to bind on previous as well. I updated my answer

Comment: Ah. Duh. I [changed it a little](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjt5wz-wstmqz?file=app/datepicker-start-view-example.ts) so that it still works when you change to month and year views. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `@Input() dateClass: (date: D) => MatCalendarCellCssClasses` property of `mat-datepicker`.  You provide a function that takes a date param and returns a css class.  Use the function to decide which dates should have the css class.

Every time the user changes the display, i.e. moves to another month, the function is called for every date in the display.

And finally, you may need to include the css class in a global file and not in the css file associated with your component (research "View Encapsulation" for more).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done through css. Here for example I am chsnging the color of dates of the weekends:

```
.mat-calendar-table {
   td:first-child > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content {
     color: red;
   }
   td:nth-child(7) > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content {
     color: red !important;
   }
}
```