# Angular material: datepicker highlighting weekends

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-material-6

I would like to highlight weekends (Saturday and Sunday) on the datepicker.

I have tried readapting the lockedweekendfilter that uses boolean for day position 0 (Sunday) and position 6 (Saturday). This code is from the Material site version 6. However, it works only for disabling dates. I don't want to disable Sunday and Saturday.

```
@Injectable()
export class InjectDatePickerGeneral {
    constructor() {}

    lockedWeekendFilter(d: Date): boolean {
        const date = new Date(d);
        const day = date.getDay();
        // Prevent Saturday and Sunday from being selected.
        return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
    }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to add a class for Saturday and Sunday in the datepicker so I can change the color and perhaps the background too.

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761382/stylizing-specific-days-from-the-material-datepicker-in-angular

Comment: Hi Jay Shukla, thank you. The dateClass: property only exists for Material 8. This is why I had to specify that I am using Material 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable using only CSS... extending the example shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761382/)

relevant **CSS**:

```
::ng-deep .mat-calendar-body > tr > td:nth-child(6) > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content,
::ng-deep .mat-calendar-body > tr > td:nth-child(7) > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content { color:red !important; }
::ng-deep .mat-calendar-body > tr > td:nth-child(6),
::ng-deep .mat-calendar-body > tr > td:nth-child(7) {  background: lightyellow;}
```

complete [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjt5wz-fk7g5i) with `Material 5.2.4` & `angular 5.2.4`

Comment: Great help! Thank you so much Akber!

Comment: This is what I did using your method:
.mat-calendar-table {
  td:nth-child(7) > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content {
    color: #dfa5a5 !important;
  }
  td:first-child > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content {
    color: #dfa5a5 !important;
  }
}
.mat-calendar-body
  > tr:first-child
  > td:last-child
  > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content {
  color: #dfa5a5 !important;
}

Comment: Work only if week with 7 days, but if 1day if Thursday or greater weekends will not highlight

Answer (score 0):

To make CSS work properly for every month, "dateClass" property can be used.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<mat-datepicker [dateClass]="dateClass"></mat-datepicker>

//TS
dateClass = (d: Date) => {
    const date = d.getDay();
    return date === 0 || date === 6 ? "weekend" : "weekday";
  };

/* CSS */
.weekend > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content {
  color: red
}
.weekday > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content {
  color: blue
}
```

References:

> https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api
> https://www.angularjswiki.com/material/datepicker/