# Angular: Mat-Calendar highlight weekend

Tags: css, angular

It's based [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57273637/angular-material-datepicker-highlighting-weekends)

In my mat-calendar I need to highlight the weekends (Saturday and Sunday), I have to put another color for difference about working day. But I don't know how I have to do.

The answer that is done in the post only works with a complete week.

So, there are any solution for this?

Comment: "The answer that is done in the post only works with a complete week." That is not true, the css selector selects the 6th and 7th child of each row, which are saturday and sunday. The other question has already the correct answer

Comment: Can you add some clarifications? On the link you posted the stackblitz example seems to work as expected. Maybe we are missing out your point,

Comment: That's not true, @FlorenciaCames . If you see the stackblitz example, only remarks when the week is complete. But when the week don't have 7 days (for example, you can see Mar 2018 or another), you will see that the weekend is not remarked...

Comment: I will try the other question, @MoxxiManagarm